# Dividing two SQL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm just trying to learn how to take a value from a column, in this case how much JJ spent on product a, and divide it by the sum of the total Product A sales and turn it into a percentage.

My SQL understanding is pretty low level right now, so the simpler the response the better.

```
SELECT 
    JJ / Result * 100 AS percentage
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ([Product A] AS JJ
     FROM [Test].[dbo].[TableA]
     WHERE [Customer Name] = 'JJ' 


    SELECT SUM([Product A]) AS Result 
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[TableA]   
)
--JJ/Result * 100 = ProdAPercentSales)
```

Comment: It would help us if you actually posted the schema for your table(s), and sample data for each table, and what the required output is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` expression to find JJ's purchases, and divide their sum with the total sum:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE [Customer name] WHEN 'JJ' THEN [Product A] ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM([Product A]) * 100 AS [Percentage]
FROM   [Test].[dbo].[TableA]
```